# More efficient way of implementing a countdown timer/clock?

Tags: c#, .net, performance, user-interface

I'm writing a small lap counter for slot car races as a little home project. I want to implement a countdown timer, which I've done with the following as a test:

```
private Thread countdownThread;
private delegate void UpdateTimer(string update);
UpdateTimer ut;
public LapCounterForm()
{
   InitializeComponent();
   //...
   ut += updateTimer;
   countdownThread = new Thread(new ThreadStart(startCountdown));
}

private void startCountdown()
{
    Process.GetCurrentProcess().ProcessorAffinity = new IntPtr(1);
    Process.GetCurrentProcess().PriorityClass = ProcessPriorityClass.High;
    Thread.CurrentThread.Priority = ThreadPriority.AboveNormal;
    System.Diagnostics.Stopwatch stopwatch = new Stopwatch();
    long time = 0;
    stopwatch.Start();

    while (stopwatch.ElapsedMilliseconds <= 5000)
    {
        time = 5000 - stopwatch.ElapsedMilliseconds;
        TimeSpan ts = TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(time);
        ut(ts.Minutes.ToString().PadLeft(2, '0') + ":" + ts.Seconds.ToString().PadLeft(2, '0') + ":" + ts.Milliseconds.ToString().PadLeft(3, '0'));
    }

}

private void updateTimer(string text)
{
    if (this.InvokeRequired)
    {
        this.Invoke(new Action<String>(ut), new object[] { text });
    }
    else
    {
        lblCountdownClock.Text = text;
    }
}
```

When I start my thread, it works. I get my 5 second countdown like I want, but I can see that I'm using a lot of CPU in the process (12% of my 8 thread i7 2600k).

I figure I can reduce this load a lot by only updating the UI every 10 milliseconds instead of every millisecond, but I have no idea how to do such, other than using `if(time % 10 == 0)` before making the `TimeSpan` and updating the UI but I suspect that will be just as inefficient thanks to the while loop.

Am I reinventing the wheel? I'd like my timer to be as accurate as possible (at least for the slot car lap time recordings, perhaps the UI does not need to be updated so often).

EDIT: I tried commenting out the actual string manipulation and UI update as suggested in the comments. Now when I start my thread my entire UI hangs until the thread exits and I still get 12% CPU usage. I suspect that while loop is eating up a lot of CPU time.

**Update:** I went with the multimedia timer ([here](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/5501/The-Multimedia-Timer-for-the-NET-Framework)) posted by Kohanz as well as Daniel's answer. I no longer use another thread at all, I just make one of those timer objects and have a tick event handler calculating the time between clicking the start button and the tick event. I can even set the period for my ticks to 1ms so I get my cool looking countdown, and it's apparently using 0% CPU :) I'm quite happy with this.

Comment: You may create another thread, responsible for the UI update, that enters a sleep for N milliseconds after updating.

Comment: Have you seen the Timer class http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.timer.aspx that .Net has?

Comment: If you don't mind me asking: who is capable of reading 10 millisecond changes on a ui? Wouldn't something like an update every 100 or 200 ms be sufficient? Then you might just use a regular timer.

Comment: `Timer` doesn't have the accuracy I'm looking for. I suppose I could use a timer to update the UI though.

Comment: @Alex nobody can read it, but it looks cooler :) I'll compromise if needed, I just absolutely love the look of it updating so quickly.

Comment: It sure looks good, but you may have to find a compromise between looks and performance. =)

Comment: @LoganDam To further Alex's point, I think there is a happy medium, perhaps around 50ms or more? I doubt your display even refreshes as fast as you are updating the UI.

Comment: String manipulation and redrawing the UI can actually have a pretty big impact on performance, but there's a simple way to test it.  Just comment out that line and see if your performance gets better.

Comment: A higher-precision multimedia timer for .NET: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/5501/The-Multimedia-Timer-for-the-NET-Framework

Comment: @Kohanz a 60 Hz display refreshes every 16.7 ms. To make sure you get at least one update per refresh a 10ms interval seems just about right.

Comment: @Logan Dam: you will always use 12% of your CPU, because you have a dedicated thread that never sleeps or blocks:  1 core out of 8 fully occupied: 1/8 => 12.5% CPU usage. The only thing that changes is what it spends most of its time on (string formatting, UI updates or updates of the `time` property. You will need a different design that does not fully use a dedicated thread to change that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Dont, just DONT go down this road. You are completely thinking of this in the wrong way. You are basically forcing your thread to freeze for no benefit.

Basically any game works this way: you have an update loop, and whenever that triggers you do neccessary stuff. So for instance if you want to know how much time, you ask some kind of "timer" how much has passed since something happened

Here's a much better way to handle this:

```
class MyStopwatch {
    private DateTime _startTime;
    private DateTime _stopTime;

    public void start() {
        _running = true;
        _startTime = DateTime.Now;
    }

    public void stop() {
        _stopTime = DateTime.Now;
        _running = false;
    }

    public double getTimePassed() {
        if(_running) {
            return (DateTime.Now - _startTime).TotalMilliseconds;
        } else {
            return (_stopTime - _startTime).TotalMilliseconds;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Interesting, I had not thought of doing it like this. I'll definitely do that for the actual lap times, but I still want my countdown timer. I think I'll combine this with updating the UI much less frequently, thanks! :)

Comment: But... here's the issue, your "while"-loop guarantees that your thread will use 100% of the cpu on the thread you created. You tell it "keep trying the following lines of code" until time has passed. That guarantees ~100% usage on that thread.

Comment: And also, as it is now, that thread updates UI everytime it triggers. So that pushes two threads to 100% usage. Now I don't know what framework you use to do this, but if the UI would "redraw" every time you trigger that callback, it would eat up 100% on that thread as well. But luckily, that is not the case. You have to think about it in ways of "something happens" then I should read the timer and see how much time has passed. Sort as, "Lap starts" and "Lap ends" or "UI Needs to update and show elapsed time". THEN you read time, otherwise, you don't

Comment: Note that .Net provides you with a high resolution stopwatch: `System.Diagnostics.Stopwatch` that does exactly this.

Comment: Sorry, my bad, thought stopwatch required forms or some other big assembly but I now see that it's part of .net System.Diagnostics. And that would indeed be a better solution.

Answer (score 1):

A bit after the fact, but this shows a way in which you might achieve what you need:

```
public class LapTimer : IDisposable
{
    private readonly System.Diagnostics.Stopwatch _stopWatch = new System.Diagnostics.Stopwatch();
    private readonly ConcurrentDictionary<string, List<TimeSpan>> _carLapTimes = new ConcurrentDictionary<string, List<TimeSpan>>();
    private readonly Action<TimeSpan> _countdownReportingDelegate;
    private readonly TimeSpan _countdownReportingInterval;
    private System.Threading.Timer _countDownTimer;
    private TimeSpan _countdownTo = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(5);

    public LapTimer(TimeSpan countdownReportingInterval, Action<TimeSpan> countdownReporter)
    {
        _countdownReportingInterval = countdownReportingInterval;
        _countdownReportingDelegate = countdownReporter;
    }

    public void StartRace(TimeSpan countdownTo)
    {
        _carLapTimes.Clear();
        _stopWatch.Restart();
        _countdownTo = countdownTo;
        _countDownTimer = new System.Threading.Timer(this.CountdownTimerCallback, null, _countdownReportingInterval, _countdownReportingInterval);
    }

    public void RaceComplete()
    {
        _stopWatch.Stop();
        _countDownTimer.Dispose();
        _countDownTimer = null;
    }

    public void CarCompletedLap(string carId)
    {
        var elapsed = _stopWatch.Elapsed;
        _carLapTimes.AddOrUpdate(carId, new List<TimeSpan>(new[] { elapsed }), (k, list) => { list.Add(elapsed); return list; });
    }

    public IEnumerable<TimeSpan> GetLapTimesForCar(string carId)
    {
        List<TimeSpan> lapTimes = null;
        if (_carLapTimes.TryGetValue(carId, out lapTimes))
        {
            yield return lapTimes[0];
            for (int i = 1; i < lapTimes.Count; i++)
                yield return lapTimes[i] - lapTimes[i - 1];
        }
        yield break;
    }

    private void CountdownTimerCallback(object state)
    {
        if (_countdownReportingDelegate != null)
            _countdownReportingDelegate(_countdownTo - _stopWatch.Elapsed);
    }

    public void Dispose()
    {
        if (_countDownTimer != null)
        {
            _countDownTimer.Dispose();
            _countDownTimer = null;
        }
    }
}

class Program
{
    public static void Main(params string[] args)
    {
        using (var lapTimer = new LapTimer(TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(100), remaining => Console.WriteLine(remaining)))
        {
            lapTimer.StartRace(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(5));
            System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(2000);
            lapTimer.RaceComplete();
        }
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
}
```

Comment: Using stopwatch is indeed the way to go, however, I think this example is way to complex to showcase how to use it.

Comment: @Daniel MesSer: You are right, maybe I got a bit carried away. Wanted to show one way to solve keeping track of laptimes and get your UI updates in one go.